# Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Recently Firebase Firestore was launched. After going through the documentation, I am confused how exactly Firebase Firestore is different Firebase Realtime Database and what are the situations in which Firestore should be used over Realtime Database as Realtime Database provides almost all the functionalites which Firestore provides (Querying, Security, Offline Capabilities).

Comment: Firebase offers two cloud-based, client-accessible database solutions that support realtime data syncing:
Realtime Database is Firebase's original database. It's an efficient, low-latency solution for mobile apps that require synced states across clients in realtime.
Cloud Firestore is Firebase's new flagship database for mobile app development.It improves on the successes of the Realtime Database with a new, more intuitive data model.Cloud Firestore also features richer, faster queries and scales better than the Realtime Database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore

Answer (score 4):

In Realtime database of Firebase, it provides only the following features

- Stores data as one large JSON tree.
- Simple data is very easy to store.
- Complex, hierarchical data is harder to organize at scale.

But in Firestone completely different data structure has been follow.

- Stores data in documents organized in collections.
- Simple data is easy to store in documents, which are very similar to JSON.
- Complex, hierarchical data is easier to organize at scale, using subcollections within documents.
- Requires less denormalization and data flattening.

For more detailing you can visit the following link: [Difference between Realtime Vs Firestone](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore)